# Generics in React TSX Files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, tsx

This might be a simple question but can't find the answer for it online. In a `ts` file I can define a function like this:

```
const lastGeneric = <T>(arr: Array<T>): T => { 
   return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

However, if I attempt to do this in a `tsx` file, I receive a bunch of syntax errors, as it assumes I'm trying to create `JSX` with a component called `T`

[image]

Is there an alternative way of defining the above function in a `tsx` file? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from captain's solution, you can define your generic types in a `type` statement where JSX won't be parsed:

```js
type SomeFunc = <T>(arr: Array<T>) => T;

const lastGeneric: SomeFunc = arr => { 
   return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just add extra comma after `T` generic:

```js
const lastGeneric = <T,>(arr: Array<T>): T => { 
   return arr[arr.length - 1];
}
```

My answer probably is a duplicate. Feel free to flag it. I just cant find the original one.

This issue occurs because of jsx. TS is unsure how to parse angle brackets